# How do you group by rows in VBA such that the values in row x are unique and the values in row y are summed up?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there in VBA an equivalent function of the group by function in pandas (Python)? The groupby function does the following

[image]

```
df.groupby(['Name']).sum()
```

[image]

The line essentially returns each unique Name with in the Apples column the sum of the apples of each name. Currently I add data to a sheet which is linked to a pivot table (I refresh the pivot table time with a macro), a second sheet copies the data from the pivot table and paste it hard. Within the second sheet I use some vlookups and other functions to calculate some extra data. But I prefer to group by the data in the first sheet so that I don't need the pivot table and second sheet (much cleaner, cleaner file, smaller file etc.).

Comment: use a pivot table.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for your repsonse! The pivot table feels like a lot of hassle for a simple task. But in your opinioin that is the only solution?

Comment: It is the easiest. Other wise you must loop the rows to get the unique list then loop again to get the sums.

Comment: If your data came from a database, do: `select name, sum(apples) as Num from TableName group by name`

Comment: Now if you have access to the NEW Dynamic Array formulas it can be done with two formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Yeah clear, I also thought of recording a macro with dropping duplicates and then a sumifs function but that also needs a second sheet. However, this feels the same as the current solution, a lot of hassle for a simple task.

Comment: @mnieto what do you mean with from a database? It is date retrieved from Navision, which I copy into the Excel sheet and then execute the macro mentioned in my question. This is also a bit of a task but it only needs to be done daily but not really user friendly. I think it is also possible to download the data directly from the database (have to check). So if your tip works, it is an option to look into.

Comment: @10uss the comment from mnieto is the SQL you would use get your desired output right from the data source. It sounds like this doesn't apply to your data source if you are not familiar with the provided query. Pivot Table is by far the easiest solution here. Once you set it up once, all you have to do is refresh...